# Question about length contraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

If an observer A is in motion on a train relative to an observer on the train platform, B, and observer A shoots a laser which hits the wall and comes back, who measures the interval to be the shortest? I don’t quite get it because the train would be contracted according to B, thus distance and time would decrease would be shorter for him, but on the other hand isn’t proper time always the shortest and hence the time interval would be shorter for A?

Comment: What does "comes back" mean?  Does it come back to where it started according to A or according to B?

Comment: come back according to A

Comment: Describe your scenario better. Where is the wall ? is it on the platform ? comes back to where ? Does it come back and hit A ?

Comment: Have you drawn a spacetime diagram?

Answer (score 0):

The time is indeed shorter for A. Your reasoning about A is correct. If the time between two events is measured by a single inertial clock between the two vs a pair of synchronized clocks, the time will always be shorter for the single clock vs the pair of synchronized clocks. So A measures the shortest time.

> the train would be contracted according to B, thus distance and time would decrease would be shorter for him

The error is here. You are correct that the train is contracted according to B, but the “thus distance and time would decrease” is not correct. The problem is that the length of the train is not the same as the distance that the light travels according to B.

When the light travels in the same direction as the train, the path of the light is longer than the length of the train. When the light travels in the opposite direction, the path is shorter than the length of the train. It is the length of this path that determines the time, not the length of the train.